# Understanding a large scientific code base (diagrams, notes, annotations, etc.)

Tags: annotations, doxygen

I often have situations where I'm put on a project and have to get to know in detail a large code base written by someone else. What tools have people found useful for understanding a large code base? I'm specifically looking for tools that help give big picture, and higher level understanding. For example, I've started using Doxygen to create diagrams and documentation, even when the project code base itself doesn't use Doxygen in the comments. Are there other tools that can automatically create diagrams or documentation based on the code itself? What have people found useful?

To take it one step further, I'm often working on code bases which involve scientific computing (lots of equations). Often what I'll do is print out a paper copy of the more mathematically oriented code and translate code into typical mathematical notation. Are there tools people have used for creating a markup separate from the code (notes, annotations, preferrably with free-form writing or Latex understanding)? I use Mendeley for keeping notes on journal articles, and think doing the same would be OK for code, but I'd really like to be able to see the equations in mathematical notation. I've seen people use Knuth's WEB, which marries Latex documentation with code, but to me it seems to obscure rather than aid in code maintenance/development.

Comment: FIY, Doxygen can process math stuff written in comment blocs and renders it as images in the HTML output using either Latex or MathJax. Of course, that could need some editing, [see this page](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/formulas.html).

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about this functionality. This will make generating documentation from code easier once I can get Doxygen comments into the code.